# Python - Having issues looking for an asterisk in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, header

I'm trying to open a load of csv files and record what row the headers start on. The most reliable way to determine the header row is to scan down the first column until you find "*", then you know the headers are on the row above.

Files might look something like:

```
Random Text, Random Text, Random Text
Random Text, Random Text, Random Text
Random Text, HEADER, HEADER
*,Values,Values
*,Values,Values
*,Values,Values
```

I use the following code and it's usually quite reliable:

```
with open(f,"r") as csvfile:
    read_rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in read_rows:
        if row[0]!="*": 
            header_row_number=read_rows.line_num
```

e.g. in my earlier example, header_row_number would return the value 3.

However, for some files, header_row_number is coming up with some completely random number like 294. Is this something to do with * being a wildcard? I can't determine a difference between the faulty file and the files that work.

Comment: can you give an example of a file for which this doesn't work?

Comment: From looking at your code, I think that you need to do *break* after the header_row_number=...
That's because, you will keep overriding it until you reach a line without '*' in the file.

Comment: There's nothing like a "wildcard" in csv. And FWIW, your files are not csv files but text files having some csv part embedded.

Comment: @Phydeaux The file is pretty big so not sure how to upload it. I think Tom has the answer though. There must be something different about this file that means row 294 is being treated as a row when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Use a service such as [`pastebin`](https://pastebin.com/) to upload your file to, then post the link here as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to reading this type of file in is to use Python's [`dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) function from `itertools`. This lets you specify a condition for which rows to drop before you start actually reading the data.

```
from itertools import dropwhile
import csv

f = 'input.csv'

with open(f, "rb") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    data = list(dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] != '*', csv_input))

print data
```

So, for the data you have given, you would see the following printed:

```
[['*', 'Values', 'Values'], ['*', 'Values', 'Values'], ['*', 'Values', 'Values']]
```

On Python 2.x, you should open your file in binary mode. If you are using Python 3.x, you should use:

```
with open(f, 'r', newline='') as f_input:
```